# MySQL - order by string date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sql-order-by

I have a meta value which is being joined onto my posts which is the date. I want to be able to only get future posts but this date is a varchar and is in the format of

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

This is what I've tried so far but doesn't seem to work properly

```
select `posts`.*, `storage_varchars`.`meta_value`

from `posts` left join `storage_varchars` on 
       `posts`.`id` = `storage_varchars`.`post_id` 
where `parent_id` = 20 and 
         DATE(storage_varchars.meta_value) >= NOW() 
order by DATE(storage_varchars.meta_value) asc
```

Comment: what exactly you are getting ???

Comment: Could you store dates as dates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [**STR_TO_DATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, s.meta_value
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN storage_varchars s ON p.id = s.post_id 
WHERE parent_id = 20 AND STR_TO_DATE(s.meta_value, '%d-%m-%Y') >= CURRENT_DATE() 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(s.meta_value, '%d-%m-%Y') ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select `posts`.*, `storage_varchars`.`meta_value`

from `posts` left join `storage_varchars` on 
       `posts`.`id` = `storage_varchars`.`post_id` 
where `parent_id` = 20 and 
         STR_TO_DATE(storage_varchars.meta_value, '%d %M %Y') >= NOW() 
order by STR_TO_DATE(storage_varchars.meta_value, '%d %M %Y') DESC
```

[STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)